# How to draw in Panel Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, line, draw, mxml

I have a problem when i want to draw the line in the panel. I don't know how to do that, please explain me...

I'm trying to put the SpriteVisualElement in the panel but i get "component declaration is not allowed here" from Flex builder. 
Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.graphics.SolidColorStroke;

        import spark.primitives.Line;



        private function drawLine():void 
        {
            var myShape:Shape = new Shape();
            myShape = new Shape() ;


            myShape.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x00008B, .75);
            myShape.graphics.moveTo(500, 500);

            myShape.graphics.lineTo(25, 45);
            spr.addChild(myShape);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<mx:Button label="Click" click="drawLine()" />
<mx:Panel  y="30" width="400" height="250" layout="vertical" title="Panel" borderColor="#008040" fontFamily="Arial" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="13">

<mx:Text text="Drawing.." fontWeight="bold"/>
        <s:SpriteVisualElement width="500" height="500" id="spr"/>
</mx:Panel>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spark Panel

```
<s:Panel>
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but line goes over the panel and get out of panel borders @Timofei Davydik (Как вписать её в панель? и чтобы можно было зумить, не подскажете?)

Comment: Well, you're drawing it from (500;500), but your panel is 400x250

Comment: Yes @Timofei Davydik, i understand that, my question is how can i enable a scrollbar for the panel to fit the line in the panel or can i enable zoom like in google maps?